# Create PDF with specific ranges in one sheet with using Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I can create pdf in a range but number of pages cannot be standardized. so is there any possiblity to update my macro to create 4 page pdf within my known range.

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim s(1) As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String
Dim pg1 As Range
Dim pg2 As Range
Dim pg3 As Range
Dim pg4 As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
     With ws.PageSetup
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
Set pg1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K92")
Set pg2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A93:K164")
Set pg3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A165:K237")
Set pg4 = ActiveSheet.Range("A239:K313")
Set r = Union(pg1, pg2, pg3, pg4)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    If fso.FileExists(s(0)) Then
        '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
        s(1) = fso.GetExtensionName(s(0))
        If s(1) <> "" Then
            s(1) = "." & s(1)
            sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), ".pdf")


                r.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=sNewFilePath, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End If
    Else
        '//Error: file path not found
        MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
```

this is not working as i imagine.
i have also tried `hpagebreaks.add`and i cannot manage it.

so do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to copy each of those ranges to a new worksheet, set the `PrintArea` on those worksheets to be the area of that range, then select all the worksheets. Once you have the worksheets selected,  you can use `ExportAsFixedFormat` to create the PDF.

Comment: actually, this is a kind a form and all of them should be in same sheet. normally this is easy if they are in different sheets.

Comment: @dwirony the use of `union()` will put each of those ranges as their own pages in the exported file.  Selpaq, are you having an issue that the printing parameters (margins, etc.) from each user are pushing some of those print areas off the page onto the next page?

Comment: @cyril yes all those ranges should be kept in their own pages. but headers can be jump other sheets or the last row. this is really important form and more than 50 people all over the globe use this. and I cannot  set their printarea by one by manually.

Comment: @SelpaqM you will need to set the print area, including margins/header/etc., e.g., adding `.FitToPagesWide = 1`, before you `ExportAsFixedFormat`.  After that, you need to set the argument for `IgnorePrintAreas` to false to use your prescribed printing criteria.

Comment: when i checked the form with using ctrl+P margins/headers etc for each printers are set to 0 however, pages are still change but not in wide direction. really it seems very easy but i think i cannot see very little point. cant catch it

Comment: @SelpaqM i don't see in your code where you have set the margins.  Maybe that is the piece that is missing?

Comment: i have added and checked for 4 different printer setting. just 1 of them is failed for 2 row, for 1 page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"1 of them is failed for 2 row, for 1 page"*?  I think I'm stuck as setting those margin parameters, stating what the header/footer should read (that's one thing I've tried otherwise that isn't in your code), and then using union() to export as pdf has worked on the two machines I've tested (note that one system is running x86 and other x64 of Excel on 1803 Win10 and 1909 Win10, respectively).

Comment: Hi @cyril i have already editted my code on question section. Can you please advise me where is my mistake bu the way i am using x64 office 365 with 1909 win10. Rest of the tried laptops are same.

Comment: today, I sent form to teammates to use it. unfortunately, still same issue exist. feedbacks for 7-8 pages not 4 pages.

Comment: hi @Cyril you have mentioned "tried otherwise that isn't in your code), and then using union() to export as pdf has worked" what was the code that you tried and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I have follow your footstep and asked to my friend for a fresh eyes. he just basically solved it with using record macro. it works now.
@cyril thanks to you and for your time.

```
   Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = True
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 4
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = False
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$C$1:$K$312"
    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
    Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("C93")
    Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(2).Location = Range("C165")
    Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(3).Location = Range("C239")

    Dim FileName As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    With Worksheets("Final")

        FileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
                               .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=Left(FileName, InStr(FileName, ".") - 1), _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the requested code which I tried when testing (this is very similar to what you have in your code, using `Union()` and then exporting):

Example code below:

```
Private Sub printToPDF()
    Dim printArea1 As Range
    Set printArea1 = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(11, "R"))
    Dim printarea2 As Range
    Set printarea2 = Cells(61, "A")
    Dim completePrintRange As Range
    Set completePrintRange = Union(printArea1, printarea2)
    completePrintRange.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "Test", , , , , , True
End Sub
```

Note that the export will have each range on its own page in the PDF.  The run-over from columns goes to its next page, e.g., `printArea1` is on two pages.  This is tied to paper size and zoom.

Comment: Unfortunately, that code is not worked for me. still getting same issue. i think `xlpagebreakmanual` can solve my problem but it cannot be set for more than 1 known range.

Comment: Understood, @SelpaqM .  The code was provided purely as resolving the request for the situation in which I tested.  My only other suggestion would be to set the paper... 11x17 paper, tied with your `IgnorePrintArea` may fix an issue.  The question I would have back to you is are your ranges going to long (rows) or too wide (columns)?  A specific paper setting might help resolve this across users, particularly if width is an issue where a landscape 11x17 could very much help.